# compile duration increased massively after adding e-conomic service reference

Tags: c#, service-reference

Recently I've added a service reference to e-conomic. However, this meant that the service reference is downloaded and compiled with my project every time I compile.

That takes a long long time, sometimes up to a minute, just to compile a relatively small project.

This is the web service:
https://api.e-conomic.com/secure/api1/EconomicWebService.asmx?wsdl

As you can see, the web service is quite massive, and that is why it takes so long every time I need to compile. Is there any way to make sure my project compiles, without having to recompile the web service over and over again?

It's growing quite frustrating.

I've already written quite a bit of code with this web service (Crying every time I needed to compile!), so it would be awesome if I didn't have to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dedicated assembly to host the service proxy. Then reference this assembly in your main project(s). Finally tweak you MSBuild to not compile automatically the service project - assuming it's part of the same solution - and voila!

If an update should be made simply recompile the project manually.